# Print blank line after each group of rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table to find the given value's before and after rows.

For example want to show 2 rows before and after of the given column `col2` value `125` and also want to print the blank line after each group.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE PreTest
(
 col1 int,
 col2 int,
 col3 date,
 col4 time
);
```

Sample Data:

```
insert into PreTest values(111,123,'2018-01-01','00:10:11'),
                          (111,124,'2018-01-01','00:10:12'),
                          (111,125,'2018-01-01','00:10:17'),
                          (111,126,'2018-01-01','00:10:16'),
                          (111,127,'2018-01-01','00:10:13');
insert into PreTest values(111,228,'2018-01-02','10:13:01'),
                            (111,229,'2018-01-02','10:13:11'),
                            (111,125,'2018-01-02','10:13:02'),
                            (111,237,'2018-01-02','10:13:30'),
                            (111,232,'2018-01-01','10:13:04');
insert into PreTest values(111,339,'2018-01-03','11:10:01'),
                            (111,338,'2018-01-03','11:10:04'),
                            (111,125,'2018-01-03','11:10:02'),
                            (111,340,'2018-01-03','00:10:11'),
                            (111,333,'2018-01-01','11:10:03');
```

Query:

```
WITH C1 AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by col3,col4) rn,*
    FROM PreTest
)
SELECT * FROM 
(

    SELECT * FROM C1 WHERE rn IN (SELECT rn FROM C1 WHERE col2 = '125')
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM C1 WHERE rn IN ( SELECT rn - 1 FROM C1 WHERE col2 = '125') 
    UNION       
    SELECT * FROM C1 WHERE rn IN ( SELECT rn - 2 FROM C1 WHERE col2 = '125') 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM C1 WHERE rn IN ( SELECT rn + 1 FROM C1 WHERE col2 = '125') 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM C1 WHERE rn IN ( SELECT rn + 2 FROM C1 WHERE col2 = '125')
) a
```

**Expected Output**:

```
rn                   col1        col2        col3       col4
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------------
4                    111         127         2018-01-01 00:10:13.0000000
5                    111         126         2018-01-01 00:10:16.0000000
6                    111         125         2018-01-01 00:10:17.0000000
7                    111         132         2018-01-01 10:13:04.0000000
8                    111         232         2018-01-01 10:13:04.0000000

12                   111         128         2018-01-02 10:13:01.0000000
13                   111         130         2018-01-02 10:13:02.0000000
14                   111         125         2018-01-02 10:13:02.0000000
15                   111         229         2018-01-02 10:13:11.0000000
16                   111         129         2018-01-02 10:13:11.0000000

22                   111         139         2018-01-03 11:10:01.0000000
23                   111         141         2018-01-03 11:10:02.0000000
24                   111         125         2018-01-03 11:10:02.0000000
25                   111         338         2018-01-03 11:10:04.0000000
26                   111         138         2018-01-03 11:10:04.0000000
```

Comment: This should be done in the front end, not the database. It is a presentation issue, not a data issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with Sean that there is no good reason to ever want to do this in SQL Server as opposed to the presentation layer, it can be done.

You would need to use a `gaps and islands` approach to determine at which point your groups change, and insert an artificial row of blank values at those points in the ORDER BY.

This means that if you want a blank row between row number 4 & 5, you would need to CAST the row number as a decimal and add a blank row with row number 4.5 or something like that.